# Export matplotlib 3d plot to model

Tags: python, 3d, matplotlib

I am generating 3d graphs in matplotlib and am generally pleased with the results. One thing I have noticed, however, is that the performance of the default 3d viewer is very slow with a few hundred points of data. Is there any way to export the generated graph to a model that could be viewed in some other 3d model viewer?

Comment: Not really, no.  (It's possible to write one, but there isn't anything at the moment.) Have a look a Mayavi (particularly mlab: http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/mlab.html ) for a more robust 3D plotting environment.

Answer (score 0):

No, not unless you write it ;).  `mayavi`  [(docs)](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/index.html) which is a openGL based renderer might do better.  You might also want to look in to [vtk](http://www.vtk.org/).

community wiki because this is basically Joe Kington's answer from the comments.